# How to create a net falling on an object (cocoon)?

Tags: node-editor, network

I am trying to prepare an animation that more or less shows the operation of the preparation: drops of the preparation fall on the worm and a net begin to form on its surface, the net wraps around the worm like a cocoon and then completely immobilizes it (blocks its vital functions and the worm dies).
I can show it in 2 ways:

1. one drop falls on the worm and it forms a whole net that wraps around the worm
2. a few drops fall on the worm in different places, and in these places, a network is formed on the worm, which over time forms one large network surrounding the worm

The animation will show a cockroach, but the preparation is also used for smaller insects of a different structure.

Could you please point me to the tools I should use to achieve this effect? I don't expect a ready-made solution, but rather guidance on what to use and how. As far as I know, I should be using the animation nodes plugin.
My previous methods of presenting this animation do not reflect this mode of action (what I realized after showing the effect), and I am not entirely satisfied with the appearance of the network (it should be the same on the entire surface, and in my case, you can see triangles and squares - more appropriate triangles).
Can anyone tell me something how to do it?
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by drops of preparation?

Comment: also you can animate the visibility of the net by mixing a transparent node with a procedural mask to get the effect of growing mask instead of animation node

Comment: “The Preparation” is not a specific thing AFAIK. What do you mean when you say The Preparation?

Comment: "drops of preparation" = drops of liquid / water. 
Thank you for tip of growing mask